# PHP5 cannot receive data from other websites

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have my virtually hosted web server. I installed it using VirtualBox, and it uses the Ubuntu  Server system. Recently, I was in a need to get data from Google Maps Geocode service. Firstly, I tried using the next code:

```
file_get_contents(URL);
```

After getting the timeout error, I tried using cURL also:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $gm_address . "&sensor=false");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Yet again, I got a timeout error.

I suspect that Ubuntu does not allow PHP to make calls to other websites. I am not an Linux or Ubuntu expert, so I did not know how to tackle the firewall settings, or settings that would allow PHP to make those calls.

In short, how do I change the settings that would allow PHP to get data from other websites?

Comment: Please post the cURL code that you used, then comment that you did.

Comment: I've edited the post, now it included the cURL code also.

Comment: I see the problem.  I am posting an answer

Comment: Check your firewall and your DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this cURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $gm_address . "&sensor=false"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Does the text now appear in `$result`?

Comment: Does not work. The script loads for like a minute, and again, no response. I used var_dump() to see the contents of $result, and I got a false boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your firewall settings it may be blocking the other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your php.ini has curl disabled

look for `disable_functions` in /etc/php.ini